# Managing schema changes with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, database-design, production-environment, mongo-go

How to handle if document structure after production changes.

Suppose I had 500 documents like this:

```
{
name: ‘n1’
height: ‘h1’
}
```

Later if I decide to add all the documents in below format:

```
{
name: ‘n501’
height: ‘h501’
weight: ‘w501’
}
```

I am using `cursor.All(&userDetails)` to decode(deserialize) in Go to get the output of the query in struct `userDetails`. If I modify the structure of further documents and `userDetails` accordingly, it will fail for the first 500 documents?

How to handle this change?

Comment: There is no schema in Mongo, it's one of its defining qualities.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a new field to your struct, querying old documents will not fail. Since the old documents do not have the new field saved in MongoDB, querying them will give you struct values where the new field will be its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value). E.g. if its type is `string`, it will be the empty string `""`, if it's an `int` field, it will be `0`.

If it bothers you that the old documents do not have this new field, you may extend them in the mongo console like this:

```
db.mycoll.updateMany({ "weight": {$exists:false} }, { $set: {"weight": ""} } )
```

This command adds a new `weight` field to old documents where this field did not exist, setting them to the empty string.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, but it's not worth doing it since this is just a one-time "correction".

Comment: Maybe, maybe not - there's not enough information from OP to know.